# Select all contents from all pages from a DataTable using Jquery

Tags: select, datatables

I am using a DataTable that has multiple pages in it. I use Select All (jQuery based) functionality which works well to select all records in the current page being viewed. But the problem is

I am not able to select all records across different pages in a table

If I select record in one page and move to next page , records selected in first page are lost.

**select all script**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
           $('.checkbox1').each(function() { 
              this.checked = true;  
           });
        }else{
           $('.checkbox1').each(function() { 
              this.checked = false;                      
           });         
        }
    });
});
```

Can some one help?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using jQuery on the DOM you only reach visible rows. You will need to access dataTables internal version of the table, i.e its "cache".  Here is a "checkall" function iterating over all the rows, changing the checked state for a checkbox with the class `.checkbox1` :

```js
$('#checkall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
  var checked = this.checked;
  table.column(0).nodes().to$().each(function(index) {    
    if (checked) {
      $(this).find('.checkbox1').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.checkbox1').removeProp('checked');            
    }
  });    
  table.draw();
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/05xnxzbd/**

The above can in fact be done in several different ways. This is the most simple approach, with a checkbox we know exists on the first column. Using [**`to$()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()) let us work with jQuery on the content right away.

You could iterate over `table.rows().data().each(function(..` as well and target multiple columns holding different checkboxes and so on.

Comment: Why is `table.cell(index, 0).data($(this).html());` messing up my html?

Comment: @Loko, ?? How should I know? I need to see the code, cannot say anything based on a "messing up my html"-statement. Wish I could :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Sorry I didnt mean it as in FIX MY CODE PLS. More like, in what way can that piece of code actually just mess up any html?

Comment: Hey @Loko, Cannot say, if it is plain HTML there should be no problem. However, I must admit it is *completely* unnecessary.  It was actually not such good answer; if you are using `prop` instead of `attr` then you dont need this "hack". Have updated the answer and the fiddle, hopefully it works better for you also. Thank you for pointing me to a problem with this old answer!

Comment: @davidkonrad Well glad I could help unintentinally but I found an alternative solution. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

jQuery DataTables removes elements that are not displayed on screen from DOM.

Use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) DataTables API method that gives access to all nodes in the table, not just ones displayed on screen.

```js
$('#checkall').click(function(){
    table.$('.checkbox1').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Worked fine for me :)