# Checked all the data entries in datatable

Tags: javascript, checkbox, datatables

If a user clicks the button "Select ALL", all the data in the table from page 1 until the last page should be checked. However, it will only check the first page of the list because only the first page is displayed and has class.

I have this code:

```
var clicked = false;
$("#ExportAll").on("click", function () {
    $(".ExportOrder").prop("checked", !clicked);
    clicked = !clicked;
});
```

How can I check all the data from page1 until the last page and will send all the checked data in the controller as well? It uses datatable.

> //Edited

I have modify my codes to be like this and was able to check all the column across different pages however when I clicked the Export button and only those current display will be sent to controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#orders-table').dataTable({
            stateSave: true
        });
        $("#ExportAll").on("click", function () {
            oTable.$("input[name='ExportOrder']").attr('checked', $(this.checked));
        });
    });
```

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult PostToStarShipIt(string[] ExportOrder)
{
}
```

The number of data in ExportOrder is only those in the current display list although all of the list are checked. How can I get all the checked data? Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you have a server a side pagination then you cant select all the data (which are on another page), because data chunk will be loaded from server and appended dynamically on page click

Comment: It didnt use the server side pagination. It actually uses data table

Comment: ok, so you have  all the data hard coded json object at client side

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713132/select-all-contents-from-all-pages-from-a-datatable-using-jquery

Comment: Have you seen gmail select all functionalities?